# What steps are necessary to get an App into the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, app-store

Can someone please list the steps needed to get a project setup for the AppStore. Lets assume the following

1. I do not have any certificates, provisioning profiles, distribution profiles, app id (whatever they are), etc.
2. I have an iPhone and an iPad

In addition, please specify 
1. what I would need to do if I created a second App
2. If one or more of my devices were swapped with AppleCare (or if I added new devices)

Comment: Please don't send me a link to other sites. I'd really prefer just a list of steps. I'll look up the details on how to accomplish a step if needed.

Comment: Maybe we could do it for you too?

Comment: Sorry.  You need to read several of the Apple documents carefully, as there are many many dozens of steps (too many to list here) that need to be followed exactly or you will fail.  Getting apps into the App store is Apple's reading comprehension test.  Shortcuts have caused big companies major headaches.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out all morning and I keep getting warnings about the certificate so we deleted all the certificates and are starting again from scratch

Comment: @kevindtimm - thank you for the offer but it would be more helpful if we screen shared and you can tell me what i'm doing wrong (and assist me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully read [Apple's iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/index.html) and the iOS Developer Program
Standard Program User Guide in the dev center's Provisioning Portal, then the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.  Skipping careful reading of these documents can be deadly.

Answer to your 3rd question, part 2:

If you exchange your registered device for a new one (repair, upgrade, etc.), you will have to add the new device's UDID in the portal, get new provisioning profiles, and drop those new provision files on Xcode.  Don't go over 100 devices total though, or you will be stuck and not able to use your new (repair, exchange, etc.) device for development.

Comment: I think you mean new provisioning profiles; you only need a new certificate once a year (when it expires).

Comment: I removed all certs, and mobile provisioning profiles and I created new certificates, a new App ID, and mobile provisioning profile. I added the certificates to my login keychain (my own, Apple WWDR) and I added the newly created mobile provisioning profiles and I still get the same response.

Answer (score 6):

Check the Apple Documentation first:

Make sure your app meets their guidelines
and follow the steps they provide.

[App Store Steps](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/)

This is directly from apple so this is how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

This flowchart is a good place to start

http://cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2008/11/22/iphone-development-flowchart/

Comment: Thank you for the site but I really need more help with generating a certificate for development/distribution and app id's and mobile provisioning profiles.

Comment: Did you pay the $99 and become an approved Apple Developer?  You need that in order to do distribution (even to your own device).  There are many guides (just google it), but they won't work if you are not approved.

Comment: I have a valid developer account. I'm the Program Admin (i'm just new to this and need a little help)

Comment: Let us know what part you can't do http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2